# How companies or managers deal with fluctuation in productivity over years

Tags: productivity

I am just a employee but I am trying to think how employers or managers take following into account and how they address them.

- Employee A starts working at company 999, they work really hard for 3 years... doing extra hours and all that... doing there 110% but then they stop doing the extra bits and get back to normal routine or feel like they can slow down a bit. Or it all just happens naturally. How companies see drop in performance in these case scenarios ?

How do companies deal with fluctuation in productivity over years, naturally or determinately for employees ?

**Edit**

If someone has set a high standard of themselves by working extra like thinking about processes and bugs after work, or staying late etc. in comparison to other individuals or learning about new technologies in there own time at work.

Then after few years they have a family they can only work as a regular employee there performance will be just like any other (apart from people who put in their own time to get stuff done).

Comment: Is their recent performance acceptable? There's your answer. What happened a few years ago is not relevant.

Comment: @Dukeling it's just a factious scenario I am thinking about and how managers or companies would react to it

Comment: If you were never getting paid to do the extra bits then i doubt if they would care at all as long as you are still getting the work done. They shouldn't expect you to throw in your own time for free anyway.

Comment: @Dukeling : IMHO it **is** relevant if you care for them. Happy ones make business better. Not to mention the human part of professionnal relationship. If I see someone (even with good productivity) going down, I'll talk to her/him. If they want to share, fine, if not, no problem, but they know I'm available and caring. You can use annual review, or informal meeting. I saw employees working hard/good, but having a hard time, because of personal problems, illness or just being exhausted, and you can kindly ask if any help is welcome... Hard to do that in bigger companies though, I agree.

Comment: "Doing 110%" is not sustainable, so even if you work extra, it's more likely that you'll be doing no more real extra work over a prolonged period. How do you measure the "110%", anyway?

Answer (score 3):

They deal with it by caring about what exactly gets done instead of valuing the effort.

Most of the time, after three years employees are a lot more productive just because they're more experienced.

They don't have to give 110% to get the same or even better results.

But some employees do better then others.

Managers deal with this by giving high performers raises and letting under-performers go.